# Findbugs BC_UNCONFIRMED_CAST warning

Tags: java, findbugs

I have two classes -

```
class A {}
class B extends A {}
```

And I was doing this -

```
A a = new B();
if(a instanceof B){
   doSomething((B) a); // type case a to B
}
```

doSomething method looks like this -

```
public void doSomething(B b) { .. }
```

Findbugs raised no warning in above code. But if I change the above code like this -

```
class A {
   public boolean isOfTypeB() {
      return this instanceof B;
   }
}
class B extends A {}

A a = new B();
if(a.isOfTypeB()){
  doSomething((B) a); // BC_UNCONFIRMED_CAST warning
}
```

Findbugs raises an error BC_UNCONFIRMED_CAST. I don't see much difference in both the implementations. Any suggestions, am I missing anything?

Comment: Is the error raised on the line if(a.isOfTypeB()) or on doSomething((B) a) ?

Comment: it's raised on doSomething((B) a) line. Updated the question

Comment: It might very well be the inability of findbug to determine that the method call isOfTypeB is an instanceof check.

Comment: Yeah looks like findbugs doesn't support it - http://osdir.com/ml/java.findbugs.general/2006-12/msg00014.html

Comment: The warning is correct in _this_ case since `isOfTypeB()` is not `final`. One could override it with e.g. `return true;`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

FindBugs looks for the `instanceof` prior to `checkcast` bytecode.  You can use an `assert` to please the FindBugs warning and  future maintainers of your code.

```
A a = new B();
if (a.isOfTypeB()){
  assert a instanceof B : a.getClass(); //Safe to call getClass because 'a' is non-null.
  doSomething((B) a);
}
```

<strike>Prior to FindBugs 3.0 you could use dynamic cast to work around this warning.  Don't do this as it is detected in later versions of FindBugs.</strike>

```
A a = new B();
if (a.isOfTypeB()) {
  doSomething(B.class.cast(a));
}
```

One of the things to consider is that FindBugs detects patterns that **do** create actual bugs and patterns that **can** create actual bugs.  The 'instanceof' keyword and Class.cast behavior can’t be overridden but 'isTypeOfB' can be overridden.  Even if FindBugs doesn't detect that both examples of your code and mine function as expected, maybe the warning is correct on the grounds that it is advisable to not do this.

Answer (score 4):

For those who look for casting ServletResponse to HttpServletResponse, Use **instanceof** as below.

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
            FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {       

        if (response instanceof HttpServletResponse)
            noCaching((HttpServletResponse) response);

        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
```

BC_UNCONFIRMED_CAST bug will not be reported in findbugs report.